# Adjusting Size of Apple MKMapView Labels

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, mkmapview, retina-display

The map view in my app works well all round, and appears correctly on iPads. But on iPhones, the *country/state/city/etc.* labels appear extremely large and oversized. Here's a screenshot of how it looks on iPhone 8 Plus:

[image]

The width of the map view is almost maximum, close to the width of the screen.

**Q: Is there any way to adjust/reduce those label font sizes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to **Apple Dev** support, *edford,* the labels in **MKMapView** directly correlate to the *text size* settings on the device. There is no API to control this through code, as it is a user preference setting.

---

Here's the answer on the **Apple Dev** forum:

- [Adjusting Size of MKMapView Labels](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/332615)

  ---

Thank you, *edford!*